# How many points of discontinuity?

Tags: analysis

I need to prove that any monotonic function whose domain is an interval $[a;b]$ can have only finite or countable number of discontinuity points...

I don't seem to have any insightful ideas. It even raises more questions in my head. What happens if we remove a requirement for monotonicity? Can you tell me any function (whose domain is all real numbers for example) have more than countable number of discontinuity points?

Comment: Take a look at [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function) for functions discontinuous everywhere. Also, the statement you are trying to prove is apparently called [Froda's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Froda%27s_theorem).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56831/is-there-an-everywhere-discontinuous-increasing-function

Comment: @Aeolian Interesting, never heard this name. The wiki proof makes things much more complicated than they are, I find.

Comment: @julien You do have a point. A bit of Googling returned [this (problem #2)](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/loya/478-F12/Notes14.pdf), which is essentially the Wikipedia proof, but better explained.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=\begin {cases} 1&x \in \mathbb Q \\ 0 & x \not \in \mathbb Q \end {cases}$

is discontinuous at every point.

Comment: Is it appropriate to say that for this (Dirichlet function?) a set of discontinuity points has cardinality of the continuum?

Comment: @Kapitonas:  yes it is.  In fact it is the continuum.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $f$ is non-decreasing first.

At a discontinuity point $x_0$, you have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^-}f(x)< \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^+} f(x).$$

Now try to find a one-to-one mapping from the set of discontinuity points into $\mathbb{Q}$.

The non-increasing case can be treated similarly.

Your second question has already been answered many times, so I will stop here.

Comment: @GitGud Yes, of course, I just added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for that but I will raise even more questions in your head : there exists functions that are not continuous in any point. Moreover, these kind of "monstruous functions" are dense ...